# How to append just hidden files names in a directory to a file?

Tags: command-line

I need to save just hidden files names in a directory and subdirectories to a file .

What is the command that do this job ?

Comment: What do you mean by “save files to a file”? Do you want a file containing the location of each file? Or do you want a big file containing the actual *content* of each file?

Answer (score 1):

This command :

```
find /path-to-directory -name '.*' >outpu-tfile
```

Change directory name and the name of output file

This will save only the hidden files of directory to output file .

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -ldp .?* | grep -v / >> hidden_files_list.txt
```

This script looks for a hidden files names and put them into a file.